# Exposing a webapp in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am setting up a Nexus OSS on an Azure VM.
I have set it up on a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
When I connect to the webapp via an SSH tunnel, I can access the Nexus repository manager. When I try to open it directly, I cannot get it to work.

As per the Azure docs and several Stackoverflow responses, I have updated the NSG and added port 8081 to be allowed but with no success. I also check the UFW (Ubuntu Firewall) and it is not even activated.

**EDIT :**

`netstat -plant | grep 8081`

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33519         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18081/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18081/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8081          127.0.0.1:60242         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8081          127.0.0.1:60366         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8081          127.0.0.1:60244         TIME_WAIT   -
```

**EDIT2 :**

[image]

```
admin@nexus-vm:~$ sudo iptables -nL INPUT
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Comment: You sure that thing is listening on `0.0.0.0:8081` and not on `localhost:8081`? Double check (`netstat -plant`).

Comment: @evilSnobu I updated my question

Comment: Double check that NSG and `iptables -nL INPUT`. Should work.

Comment: @evilSnobu updated again

Comment: Yup, that should work. Make sure you don't have another NSG on the Subnet rather than NIC.

Comment: Just checked, I only have one NIC with one NSG applied to it. I am going berserk on this :s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172426/discussion-between-homewrecker-and-evilsnobu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the firewall of my company. Tested it over 4G and it works.